# How to read array initializer values from .NET assembly

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-assembly, il

How is it possible to read the values, let's say: '99' from an ***assembly*** containing this code?

```
using Sytem; 

public class Class1
{
    public Class1() {
        // array initializer, want to read '99', '100'... from assembly
        var a = new double[,] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 99, 100, 101 } };
        // ...
    }

}
```

### What I have done so far

The method in ILDASM:

```
.method /*06000001*/ public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void  .ctor() cil managed
// SIG: 20 00 01
{
  // Method begins at RVA 0x2080
  // Code size       29 (0x1d)
  .maxstack  3
  .locals /*11000001*/ init ([0] float64[0...,0...] a)
  .language '{3F5162F8-07C6-11D3-9053-00C04FA302A1}', '{994B45C4-E6E9-11D2-903F-00C04FA302A1}', '{5A869D0B-6611-11D3-BD2A-0000F80849BD}'
// Source File 'c:\Users\heini19\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WcfService1\ClassLibrary1\Class1.cs' 
//000005:         public Class1() {
  IL_0000:  /* 02   |                  */ ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  /* 28   | (0A)000011       */ call       instance void [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.Object/*01000001*/::.ctor() /* 0A000011 */
  IL_0006:  /* 00   |                  */ nop
  IL_0007:  /* 00   |                  */ nop
//000006:             // array initializer, want to read '99', '100' etc.
//000007:             var a = new double[,] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 99, 100, 101 } };
  IL_0008:  /* 18   |                  */ ldc.i4.2
  IL_0009:  /* 19   |                  */ ldc.i4.3
  IL_000a:  /* 73   | (0A)000012       */ newobj     instance void float64[0...,0...]/*1B000001*/::.ctor(int32,
                                                                                                         int32) /* 0A000012 */
  IL_000f:  /* 25   |                  */ dup
  IL_0010:  /* D0   | (04)000001       */ ldtoken    field valuetype '<PrivateImplementationDetails>{975506E6-7C24-4C2B-8956-C1B9CF8B80C4}'/*02000003*//'__StaticArrayInitTypeSize=48'/*02000004*/ '<PrivateImplementationDetails>{975506E6-7C24-4C2B-8956-C1B9CF8B80C4}'/*02000003*/::'$$method0x6000001-1' /* 04000001 */
  IL_0015:  /* 28   | (0A)000014       */ call       void [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers/*01000015*/::InitializeArray(class [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.Array/*01000016*/,
                                                                                                                                                            valuetype [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.RuntimeFieldHandle/*01000017*/) /* 0A000014 */
  IL_001a:  /* 0A   |                  */ stloc.0
//000008:             // ...
//000009:         }
  IL_001b:  /* 00   |                  */ nop
  IL_001c:  /* 2A   |                  */ ret
} // end of method Class1::.ctor
```

The compiler created the struct `<PrivateImplementationDetails>{975506E6-7C24-4C2B-8956-C1B9CF8B80C4}` with the field `$$method0x6000001-1`  for the initialization value and uses `RuntimeHelpers.InitializeArray` in order to initialize the new array at runtime. The original values defined in C# seem to be stored in the field and get copied by using the field handle? But how are the values laid out?

There must be some better/easier way to read those constants from the assembly?

Comment: Is this an instance of the XY problem? Why would you want to do this in the first place? What are you *actually* trying to achieve?

Comment: 'XY'? What's this? It is to be used for an assembly hash algorithm needed for assembly versioning. Changes to those constants (in code) must be detected somehow.

Comment: @HaymoKutschbach You can make it workable with some primitive-type arrays... But what will you do for arrays of objects, perhaps returned by methods? (`new[] { GetElement1(), GetElement2(), GetElement3() }`)

Comment: @HaymoKutschbach The [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)... Your doesn't seem to be an XY problem... Only a very strange problem

Comment: I am not sure but I think the individual method calls for each element would show up in the method body. The body can simply be hashed by 'MethodBody.GetILAsByteArray()'. So they will be covered.

Comment: @HaymoKutschbach Note that the "hidden special" class is called only in one case... Array of size >= 3 of numeric types. See http://goo.gl/iC6MRv

Comment: @xanatos interesting. But this case is actually one of the most popular ones - not very rare at all?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**non response**

What you are trying to do verge on the impossible (note that the single case in your example is probably doable, but probably wouldn't cover your full needs)

The `<PrivateImplementationDetails>` is created by the C# compiler only in some cases (numeric arrays over a certain size, it seems). For all the other cases, direct initialization in the constructor is done. See http://goo.gl/iC6MRv for some examples.

Note that the IL code you are seeing isn't "written in the stone"... There are no rules that dictate to a C# compiler how it should create array initializers. For example Roslyn (the link I gave is generated by Roslyn) uses a `PrivateImplementationDetails` instead of `<PrivateImplementationDetails>{975506E6-7C24-4C2B-8956-C1B9CF8B80C4}`. And who knows what code is generated by the Mono compiler.

In the most general case it isn't possible know the values of an initialized array without executing the constructor (so instantiating the class) and taking a look at the obtained object. But this clearly has other problems (the initialization of a class could have side effects, or could require parameters)

Comment: It sounds reasonable that we cannot easily learn the initialization result from the assembly. On the other hand, tools like reflector / Cecil seem to do. But maybe for the purpose of _hashing_ we could get away with simply including the 'area' of the assembly where those constants are stored. Do you think we can generalize the way _all_ compilers are handling this? They all store these constants in helper class fields, right? It might be suffient to include all fields in the hashing?

Comment: @HaymoKutschbach IlSpy simply checks for some patterns of array initializers. They probably tested it with C#, Mono C#, VB.NET and perhaps F#. The code is [here](https://goo.gl/NVR9bE). There is no guarantee that future versions of C# will produce the same pattern, or that other compilers will produce the same pattern, or that hand-written IL-code will use the same pattern.

Comment: The link is very useful! I wish I could upvote more than once :) Can you point me to some resource regarding the way the initial value is stored in the auto -generated class field? Would it be enough to also hash those internal classes? (regardless of compiler incompatibilities)

Comment: Thanks again for the XY link! Maybe your assumption was not that bad either.